# os.environ.get return None, but echo works properly

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, elementary-os

I have issue with "os.environ.get" command. I exported my variable using:

```
export MYVAR="123"
```

Then i used:

```
echo "$MYVAR"
```

And it returned my value. But when i am doing in python

```
print(os.environ.get('MYVAR'))
```

It returns None. For example:

```
print(os.environ.get('HOME'))
```

Works correctly. I tried using bashrc, zhrsc, bash_profile and it never works. I am using Linux Elementary 5.1. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: *What shell* did you export the variable from? Is Python a *new* child process of that shell?

Comment: When doing *export* it's only for the current shell, so if the python code is ran elsewhere it does not have i

Comment: `export VARIABLE` only exports that variable to new child processes started by that specific shell. Using `bashrc` or `bash_profile` tells new shells to include that variable in their exported variables list. *Existing* processes won't see the new variable, because they never inherited this from their parent.

Comment: But when I use bashrc it still cannot see my variable.

Comment: This works for me with bash: `export MYVAR="123"; python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('MYVAR'))"`

Comment: It works for me too, but i need to use it in flask app.

Comment: How/from where is the flask app started? `.bashrc` only runs for interactive shells, and it's bad practice to rely on it for things running as services. Would need to know which specific process supervision system (systemd, launched, etc) you're using to describe the best way to set an environment variable for a service that system starts.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your export of the environment variable is only limited to the shell you are using.
If you set the environment variable system-wide, it will be available to be read in your python code as well.

Set environment variable in /etc/environment for Unix based system